# Mockito injects mocks twice with JUnit 5

Tags: java, spring-boot, mockito, junit5

I started testing Spring Boot 2.0.0 and I encountered a strange behaviour with Mockito 2.17.0 and JUnit 5.1.0.

From what I saw, the way to get the mocks injected into the desired bean is to use the new `@ExtendWith` annotation with the `MockitoExtension` class.

So, here's my test class:

```
@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
class MyServiceTest {

    @Mock
    private A a;

    @Mock
    private B b;

    @InjectMocks
    private MyService myService;

    // The test methods are omitted
}
```

That seemed fine but I found that the mocks didn't get called as expected and I figured out that this was due to a different instance of `a` and `b` inside the test class and the service itself.

Actually, it's because of the `MockitoExtension` being applied twice and the second time it is applied, the `myService` field isn't evaluated to `null` (obviously) which imply that the newly created mocks (`a` and `b`) aren't set to the current `myService` instance or a new one either.

Am I forgetting something?

I assume I could handle the mocks myself but I think that it isn't the purpose of the `InjectMocks` annotation.

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like you hit Mockito issue: [mockito#1346](https://github.com/mockito/mockito/pull/1346).

It's already fixed, so you may wait for a public release or use dev build 2.17.2: https://bintray.com/mockito/maven/mockito-development/2.17.2 ([release notes](https://github.com/mockito/mockito/blob/release/2.x/doc/release-notes/official.md))